# Check nearby wifi connection periodically

Tags: android, wifi

I want to check periodically for wifi open connections. Should i write a service for it and use AlarmManager to start service or is there any other simple way of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `AlarmManager`, with a user-chosen polling period.

Comment: @Hasandroid: If you only want to "heck periodically for wifi open connections" when an activity is on-screen, I would use `postDelayed()`, though a `Timer` could work.